# Javascript: How do I check a css style and then change another css style?

Tags: javascript, css, function, styles

I'm trying to check if the `left` css property of a `div` named `#right` is equal to `0%` and then if this equals true then change the `display` property of another `div` named `#menu` to `'none'`.

I know to get a CSS style you use the following function:

```
document.getElementById("right").style.left = '0%'
```

But I can't work out how to always run this function so that as soon as the left style equals `0%`, then hide the menu div.

I have tried numerous ways of doing this and can't seem to get it to work. Perhaps there is a better way of achieving this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When is the left property updated? With JavaScript? In that case, can't you encapsulate that in a function, and each time the function is called you check if the new value is 0% and if so, hide the other element?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a Javascript function. But it must have a default value set through css first. Otherwise javascript may not read the value correctly.

Comment: Yes, the left property is updated via javascript and has a default value of 0%.

How would I go about checking the value when the function is called and hiding the element?

Comment: There are no events for CSS changes, so your best option is to look at exactly what can *cause* the style to change. Maybe a mouseover, or another javascript event, or a window resize? If nothing reliably causes it, you should use `setInterval` to repeat your function maybe 5 times per second (interval of 200). Don't repeat it too often or you will make your page slow, particularly on mobile devices.

Comment: you could create a function, e.g., `updateLeftOfRight(pixels)` to update the `left` of `#right` and add a check in this function, e.g., `if(pixels == '0%'){...; hdieTheMenu()}` and always use this function to update the `left` of `#right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: create a function

```
function setMenuDisplay() {
  var right = document.getElementById("right");
  var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
  menu.style.display = right.offsetLeft ? "block" : "none";
}
```

**Step 2**: Call this function in any event that can change the `#right` property `left` (window.onload, window.onresize or any function affecting the contents of the page)

Answer (score 0):

To think wider just use *getComputedStyle()* function. It returns strings with CSS property value of element:

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(someElement).opacity) //0.5
console.log(getComputedStyle(someElement).width) //47px
//and on, and on…
```